# Watir will not input URL into Firefox

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I haven't had issues with watir like this before and I have been searching for hours.

The error I get is the following:

```
"no sessionId in returned payload"
```

I tried using Chrome, but every time I create a new window it just shows "data:," in the url field.

How in the world do I pass a url these days?

Here is my code:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'colorize'
require 'nokogiri'


# Login Process ---
puts ("Login Process Started...").yellow
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

browser.goto 'empire.kred'
```

Comment: You don't have to declare 'watir-webdriver', Now watir is enough, Watir is not a meta gem now! Try it now, If it doesn't work out, I will tell you another way to resolve this problem. I know this problem arises in geckodriver, So let's move to legacy firefox driver where you wouldn't find this problem.

Comment: Good to know, but it didn't solve this issue, unfortunately. Should I downgrade my geckodriver then?

Comment: Are you having issues with both chrome and firefox?  If you are running chrome v56-58, you should get the latest version of chromedriver.  And--if you are running firefox with geckodriver v0.15.0--then you need to install `selenium-webdriver 3.3.0` as well.

Comment: @DillonCarter I have answered below!

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have installed WATIR 6.2.1, For that you just execute

```
gem install watir
```

And then what you need to know is, selenium 3.3.0's default driver is geckodriver, So you need to deactive that, If you deactive that, then legacy firefox driver will drive your browser, So write the below code to accomplish that

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(marionette: false)

b=Watir::Browser.new :firefox, desired_capabilities: caps
```

And also legacy firefox will drive until 47.0.2 So make sure that you install 47.0.2, To install this, Just download Firefox version 46(because you can't get 47.0.2), and then do a single upgrade and make sure that you have chosen 'never update option'(Go to option).

That's all, it's done. Now it will work for you.